# Truncating after X number of line breaks

Tags: html, css, anki

I'm doing an anki (which supports both html and css for card templates) template and I would like to integrate example sentences parsed from a dictionary. The issue is that more often than not there is way too many examples to be displayed.

The content of a typical "{{examples}}" field looks like this.

```
►…のほうに　in the direction of…; toward(s)…; to 《the east》<br>・左のほうに曲がる　bend [turn] to the left (side)<br>・左のほうに富士山が見える.　On the left (side) you can see Mt. Fuji.<br>・こちら[あちら]のほうに　this [that] way<br>・君のほうに行く　go your way; go toward you<br>・市役所より北のほうに　《located》 to the north of the city hall; 《go》 north from the city hall<br>・それはここから[駅の]東のほうにある.　It's (to the) east ┏from here [of the station].<br>・あきる野市は東京都の西のほうに位置している.　Akiruno City is situated in the western part of metropolitan Tokyo.<br>・彼は青山のほうに住んでいる.　He lives somewhere Aoyama way.<br>
```

As you can see every example sentence starts with either "►" or "・" and ends with "
".

Would there be a way to truncate the whole field to only show the first three examples and a "show more" button to display the remaining examples?

Current template:

FRONT

```
<div class=category>{{category}}</div>
<div class=kenkyusha>{{kenkyusha}}</div>

<hr>

<div class=kojien>{{kojien}}</div>
```

CSS

```
.night_mode{
}

.replaybutton {display: none;}

ul {
    padding: 0;
}

.card {
  font-family: myfont;
  font-size:13pt;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.entry {
  font-size:200%;
  color:#5566ee;
  text-align: center;
}

.reading {
  text-align: center;
}

.category {
  text-align: center;
}

.kenkyusha {
  text-align: left;
  color:#4ecab0;
}

.kojien {
  text-align: left;
  color:#4ecab0;
}

.examples {
  text-align: left;
}
```

BACK

```
<div class=entry>{{entry}}</div>
<div class=reading>{{reading}}</div>

<hr>

<div class=category>{{category}}</div>
<div class=kenkyusha>{{kenkyusha}}</div>
<div class=examples>{{examples}}</div>

<hr>

<div class=kojien>{{kojien}}</div>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @BrunoSousa Just did!